# How should I weather strip a door in an outside building?

Tags: hvac, doors

I have an office in the garage that is a standard room with insulation and an AC unit (8500 BTU AC in a 9' 3" tall room, 5" 4' wide). The room gets rather hot and I found the issue to be with the door and the hot air coming in from it. What is the best method to stop the heat from entering through the door but still leaving the opening and closing of the door functional?

facts:

- 1. Wood door (32 inches)
- 2. Clearance on bottom between ground and door, ~ 3/4"
- 3. slight space between top of door and door framing, ~ 1/8"

update: I found a fantastic tutorial that helps to solve this issue at

http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Saving-Money/Energy-Efficiency/weatherstripping-doors/Step-By-Step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of these [Twin draft guards](http://www.improvementscatalog.com/product/code/333684.do?cm_mmc=Froogle-_-OutdoorWeatherizing-_-2010-_-333684%20BRN&code-macs=MP0WFGL&code=MP0WFGL&mr%3atrackingCode=3DE8FEAF-AA35-DF11-9DA0-002219319097&mr%3areferralID=NA) for the bottom of the door.

Some [Weather strip tape](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Weather+strip&cid=14263950099339525033&ei=kxhSTLWxOaKAywXppKzJBA&sa=title&ved=0CAcQ8wIwADgA#p) might work for the top.